# Подключиться к домашней базе данных postgresql с рабочего компьютера минуя прокси

Tags: postgresql, proxy, прокси

Пытаюсь подключиться к базе данных postgreSql, которая установлена на удаленном компьютере. Из дома подключение идет нормально. Но на работе не удается установить соединение. Я так подумал, что это из-за корпоративного proxy.

Прокси обычного вида `company.proxy.ru:8080`

В настройках браузера она стоит, тем самым идет подключение к интернету через браузер, но как это сделать из GUI pgAdmin III?

И да, у меня закрыты права на любые установки программ и изменения в переменных окружения. Такие правила у нас....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP-прокси в pgAdmin III не поддерживаются. Можно лишь настроить SSH-туннель при необходимости: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/connect.html

Comment: Спасибо, пробовал, но видимо не до конца понимаю. Там на первой вкладке заполняется стандартная информация, сервер, бд и так далее, а как правильно ssh туннель описать?

Comment: @Triple-B для начала на целевой машине должен быть SSH-сервер вроде OpenSSH. Он там есть?

Comment: есть, не помню какой уже, делаю на пару с человечком

Comment: SSH-тоннель, там есть хост тоннеля, порт имя пользователя, чей хост и порт вбивать? и тот и другой пробовал....

Comment: @Triple-B Порт SSH обычно 22. Хост -- сервера, через который делаете туннель, очевидно (это же настройки туннеля).